# Правильно ли поставлены знаки?

Tags: пунктуация

"Понимаешь, на мой взгляд, наше общение зашло в тупик, поэтому, чтобы не утруждать жизнь ни тебе, ни мне, я прекращаю с тобой какое-либо общение.
Так что, будь добр, прояви ко мне хоть какое-нибудь понимание".

Нужна ли запятая после "поэтому"? Нужна ли запятая после "так что" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придаточное предложение "чтобы не утруждать жизнь ни тебе, ни мне" нужно с двух сторон выделить запятыми, так как оно находится внутри другого предложения "поэтому...я прекращаю с тобой какое-либо общение".  "Будь добр"  обособляется как вводное предложение, запятая после "так что" нужна.
Выражение "утруждать жизнь" лучше заменить на "усложнять жизнь".